# WordPress AJAX Callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have this callback where I want to retrieve a list of data from the database, when user has selected a name on a dropdown menu. However I can't seem to figure out how to return the data in a proper way, so I can display the data in a table.

Following is my code:

AJAX Callback

```
function rdc_ajax_callback() {
    global $wpdb;

    $company_id = $_POST['company_id'];

    $coupons = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
                                                'SELECT r.id, r.user_id, r.coupon, u.user_login, u.user_nicename
                                                FROM wp_rdc AS r
                                                INNER JOIN wp_users AS u ON u.id = r.user_id
                                                WHERE u.id = %d
                                                ORDER BY r.id ASC',
                                                array(
                                                    $company_id
                                                )
                                            )
                            );

    if ( $coupons ) {

        echo json_encode( $coupons );

    }

    die();
}
```

AJAX Script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#rdc-show-user-coupons").change(function() {
                var companyID = $(this).val();

                if( companyID ) {
                    var data = {
                        'action': 'rdc_call',
                        'company_id': companyID
                    };

                    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        var my_table="<table>";
                        console.log(response);
                        // $.each(response, function(i, obj){
                        //     my_table+="<tr> <td> "+obj.user_id+" </td> <td> "+obj.coupon+" </td> </tr> ";
                        // });
                        my_table+"</table>";
                        $("#rdc-result").html(my_table);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Right now I'm receiving this from the console logging:

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ,

`$wpdb->get_results( 'query', output_type);`

Therefore ,

```
    $coupons = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
            'SELECT r.id, r.user_id, r.coupon, u.user_login, u.user_nicename
            FROM wp_rdc AS r
            INNER JOIN wp_users AS u ON u.id = r.user_id
            WHERE u.id = %d
            ORDER BY r.id ASC',
            array(
            $company_id
            )
        )
    );

$result = $wpdb->get_results( $coupons , OBJECT_K);
```

Now return this variable, it contains the result set.

OBJECT_K - result will be output as an associative array of row objects, using first column's values as keys (duplicates will be discarded).

EDIT :

I think this is the issue :

the action you specified in your js is  `'action': 'rdc_call'`

Now , you should use this else the ajax will not work .

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_rdc_call', 'rdc_call' );

function rdc_call() {
//Your code to be executed after ajax call
}
```

Note : Action name should `match` the function name.

EDIT :

As you are returning `JSON type data`, modify your `$.post` this way ,

```
 $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            var my_table="<table>";
            console.log(response);
            // $.each(response, function(i, obj){
            //     my_table+="<tr> <td> "+obj.user_id+" </td> <td> "+obj.coupon+" </td> </tr> ";
            // });
            my_table+"</table>";
            $("#rdc-result").html(my_table);
        }, "json");
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm not getting anything back. Maybe something's wrong with my Javascript?

Comment: I tried, and it only returns an array saying (new String("Array")) or something like that. My actions should match the function's name. `add_action( 'wp_ajax_rdc_call', array( $this, 'rdc_ajax_callback' ) );

add_action( 'admin_footer', array( $this, 'rdb_ajax_script' ) );`

and the function's name for the call is rdc_ajax_callback() and the script's function is rdb_ajax_script()

Comment: Cool, thanks. But my array is empty, you can see my AJAX handler right here: http://pastebin.com/ef5iY3G9

Comment: Have you checked that your query is returning the expected result. ?

Comment: No, i havent, since i cant get the php database handler script to stop executing and print_r my result. A regular die wont work, any ideas?

Comment: what do you see after placing `print_r($result)` in your code , just after you get the results.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work, since the script just continues on, since it just handles the AJAX call :/ although I've tried my query in Sequel Pro and it returns the data just fine.

Comment: you have to see your results in the console, open firebug ,click on the ajax call in your console , then response there you can see the response. it will not show results on the page.

Comment: oh, ok, let me just try that :)

Comment: I got it working by editing my statement to a single line, I don't know if multiple lines could have caused the whole issue. Anyways, it works now, it returns the data just fine, last question: would it be nescessary so add a nounce in this code or is that overkill?

Comment: It's a good practice , saves you from `Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)` attacks  . It's not an overkill.